# Primefaces panelMenu bug?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

```
<p:panelMenu>
            <p:submenu label="Articoli">
                <p:menuitem value="Anagrafica" action="/articoli/anagrafica" icon="ui-icon-document" ajax="false" />
                <p:menuitem value="Importazione" action="/articoli/importazione" ajax="false" />
                <p:menuitem value="Marchi" action="/articoli/marchi" ajax="false" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Clienti">
                <p:menuitem value="Anagrafica" action="/clienti/anagrafica" ajax="false" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Vendite" icon="ui-icon-suitcase">
                <p:menuitem value="Point Of Sale" action="/vendite/pos" ajax="false" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Utilita" icon="ui-icon-calculator">
                <p:menuitem value="TestPDF" action="#{menuController.getTestPdf()}" ajax="false" />
            </p:submenu>
        </p:panelMenu>
```

This menu shows perfectly but after a little navigation it behaves in unpredictable way.

I mean I can't control the state open / closed of each submenu so, on each menuitem click and page loading, they are expanded / collapsed **randomly** !

After a little search I found that panelMenu uses client cookies for saving the submenu's states, but.... isn't it supposed to manage all that automatically?

What can I do to manually control the state of each submenu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces: expanded attribute on subMenu not taken into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484925/primefaces-expanded-attribute-on-submenu-not-taken-into-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manually control this behaviour as you can do it with the activeIndex attribute of the p:accordionPanel.

But I am facing the same problem and I found this Question on stackoverflow:
[Primefaces 3.4 p:panelMenu: unable to control the state of p:submenu and p:menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726428/primefaces-3-4-ppanelmenu-unable-to-control-the-state-of-psubmenu-and-pmenui).

The conlusion is that the panelMenu would have the same state for pages in the same application directory. Having the pages in a more sophisticated folder structure you can only wrap all your current pages in "pseudo pages" and putting these pseudo pages the same folder.

So you end up having a pseudo page like this:

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <ui:composition>
    <ui:include src="/actualPagesDirectory/actualPage.xhtml" />
  </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

It is not very nice but so far the only solution I see using the primefaces panelMenu as it is.

EDIT: My conclusion was incorrect. Having the pseudo pages like this will not change the behaviour. So it is still a no for controlling the behaviour.

Additionally I found a hint on that this problem is known and will be addressed:
[Primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22813)
But still I cannot find that this issue was addressed in primefaces 3.5.CR1.