# expanded attribute on subMenu not taken into account

Tags: primefaces, submenu

I have a panelMenu with some submenus inside whose expanded attribute is controlled on a backing bean. The issue is, the expanded status of the different submenus seems to be cached by the browser, depending on the previous status of each submenu the previous time the user was on that url, ignoring the boolean status set to expanded. The behaviour is the same with p:panelMenu and with p:menu.

You can reproduce the issue on a PF project, adding the following code to a jsf page. No backing bean required. The first time the page is loaded, the submenu in the middle will appear as collapsed. After playing a bit with the menu if the page is reloaded, the expanded attribute is not taken into account anymore, and the way the page is display responds to the last configuration the user had on the browser.

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelMenu toggleable="true">
        <p:submenu label="No expandido" expanded="false">
            <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org"/>
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Expandido" expanded="true">
            <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org"/>
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="No expandido" expanded="false">
            <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:panelMenu>
</h:form>
```

Attending to the manual, this behaviour is not the expected one:

```
           expanded - false - Boolean - Defines the state of submenu.
```

... and according to a post by Cagatay in the PF forum, panelMenu is already ready to use the expanded attribute.

Question is, i**s there a way to set the status expanded/not expanded of subMenu elements inside of a panelMenu or a menu**?

Thanks for any comment/suggestion/workaround.

Primefaces 5.2 | Tomcat 7.0.X | Chrome + IE11

Comment: Try to take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863381/how-to-retain-maintain-collapse-and-expand-states-of-ppanelmenu-even-after-a

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the stateful attribute of the panelMenu:

```
<p:panelMenu stateful="false">
```

This disables the menu from being cache to a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, the cause was having multiple `f:viewAction` inside `f:metadata`. merging them into one, solved the issue.